# Changing ModelState when authorization fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have written a custom Authorize Filter:

```
public class MyAuthenticationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter{

    // Do the authorization    
    if (!isAuthenticated)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

This filter has various conditions and in the end will set the result to `Unauthorized`, if the user is not authorized and will do nothing if the user is authorized.

It's being used in a SPA application and almost all of my methods are called from grids. In those Grids I have custom error handler that will show friendly notifications if something goes wrong. All of the errors are added to the `ModelState`.

Now, I'd like to manage unauthorized behavior and change `ModelState` when user is not authorized to do for example delete.

Please guide me how should I implement it and what methods I need to override.

**UPDATE**

I can change model state with this line:

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("", "GO AWAY!");
```

But it doesn't return anything to the user. I've tried using `IAuthenticationFilter` and adding `ModelState` error in the challenge method, and it didn't work neither.

I guess it'll work fine if I could return some `Json` data.

I need to somehow get similar behavior of this action method:

```
public ActionResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, object model)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "error");
    return Json(new[] { model}.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Is it possible? Do you have any suggestion about implementing this authorization and returning `Json` data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return any result you want by using `context.Result`, in my case I'd like to cancel Kendo Grid's changes and add a model state error that I achieved with this code:

```
public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext context)
{
    if (context.Result == null || context.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
    {
        var ModelState = context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;

        context.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult
            {
                Errors = ModelState.SerializeErrors()
            }
        };
    }
}
```